# aws s3 cp from jenkins workspace to ec2 workspace on separate aws accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

**GOAL:** When I click build, I want to copy files from jenkins workspace to ec2.(both are in same region but different aws accounts)

Background:

- jenkins is in aws account A with role J attached to it.
- an ec2 instance in aws account B and a separate role R with ec2+ssm  permissions.
- From Jenkins shell I'm assuming Role R and capturing the credentials such as acess/secret/token.
- Then pushing files from jenkins workspace to s3 bucket s3://pine/apple/ in aws account B.

Now I want to copy those files from s3://pine/apple/ to ec2's  /home/ubuntu/pear
**What I tried:**

per the aws tutorial here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/walkthrough-cli.html#walkthrough-cli-example-1

```
aws ssm send-command \
--region "us-east-1" \
--instance-ids "i-apple" \
--document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
--comment "IP config" \
--parameters commands="aws s3 sync s3://pine/apple/ /home/ubuntu/pear --debug" \
--output text
```

**Issues I'm running into:**

1. i checked the /home/ubuntu/pear and it doesn't have the data. Jenkins shows:

> COMMAND   abcdefgh    IP
> config    0   0   AWS-RunShellScript      0   1615535133.68   50  0           1615527933.68       Pending Pending 1
> CLOUDWATCHOUTPUTCONFIG        False INSTANCEIDS   i-apple NOTIFICATIONCONFIG
> COMMANDS  aws s3 sync s3://pine/apple/ /home/ubuntu/pear --debug

But the shell shows successful. The SSM Run command history on the UI shows a failure.
[image]

**Approach 2**
From jenkins shell, post assumption of role, I also tried the traditional way of

```
aws s3 sync s3://pine/apple /home/ubuntu/pear
```

but gives

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/pear'
```

Permissions are:

```
root@ip-apple:/home/ubuntu# ls -lrt
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Mar 12 00:57 test.text
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Mar 12 00:57 pear
```

What am I missing? How do I proceed? I want to use ssm so that I don't have to manage creds.

Comment: is there a way to pass sudo as part of aws s3 cp so that the folder has right perms?

Comment: I tried it like `aws ssm send-command --region "us-east-1" --instance-ids "i-apple" --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --comment "ANOTHER TEST" --parameters '{"commands":["#!/bin/bash","ifconfig","whoami","ls /home/ubuntu/test-dir", "sudo su", "aws s3 sync s3://pine/apple/* /home/ubuntu/pear/"]}' --output text
`  but it failed and ssm shows no error reason

Comment: I ran `sudo aws s3 sync s3://pine/apple /home/ubuntu/pear`  and it endedup copying files to jenkins instead of the ec2 . essentially neither session manager is working nor the other one method.

Comment: Does the SSM UI show any error details for the failure? If you click the radio button next to your instance ID and click 'View Output', is there anything? I have tried your scenario just now (without the Jenkins part) by assuming a role and running an SSM command to copy down from S3 to an ubuntu image in another account, and it works on my side. Does your `role R` have access to the bucket you are trying to sync from?